# Filter blanks from a 2d Array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets, gmail

I am pulling a 2d array of names, and adding "@gmail.com" to each of them to be passed to the gmailapp as the list of names to send the email to.  It pulls the data fine, but I need to filter out blanks so that the function runs when it encounters a blank.  I think I am not exactly understanding the filter command.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

const contacts = ss.getRange('A2:A7').getValues(); // 2D array


const filtered = contacts.filter ( function (row) {
                   return (row[1] != "");})

const emails = filtered.map(function (nameRow) { return nameRow[0] + "@gmail.com"; });
```

Comment: In your script, when ``row[1]`` is ``""``, the row is removed. For this, if you want to also remove the rows when ``row[0]`` is ``""``, how about ``const filtered = contacts.filter ( function (row) {return row[0] != "" && row[1] != ""})``? But if you want to remove only when ``row[0]`` is ``""``, please modify from``row[1]`` to ``row[0]``. If I misunderstand your question, can you provide a sample values of input and output you want? Such sample values will help users think of your solutions.

Comment: There's no `row[1]`(2nd column in current row) in A2:A7.  Only option is `row[0]` (1st column)

Comment: I thought I had tried that already.... but apparently not... changing it to 0 works! thank you!